# Why do I get different results when I run a program from testing trough Xcode and just taping the icon on the device?

Tags: xcode, ios5

I am having a really weird problem because i get completely different results between testing my program WHILE connected to the computer (trough xcode) but ON my device. and just taping the icon while not being plugged to xcode. (I think it might be coordinate issues).

So i was thinking there might be a difference between testing in these 2 ways.

Sorry i forgot to specify, I used to get the same results in both ways but then i created a singleton for my location manager instead of creating a single location manager object in each window.

This is how i am creating the Header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

// protocol for sending location updates to another view controller
@protocol LocationManagerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation*)location;
@end

@interface LocationManagerSingleton : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {

    CLLocationManager* locationManager;
    CLLocation* location;
    //id delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager* locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocation* location;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <LocationManagerDelegate> delegate;

+ (LocationManagerSingleton*) sharedInstance; // Singleton method

@end
```

and this is the implementation:

```
#import "LocationManagerSingleton.h"

//static LocationManagerSingleton* sharedCLDelegate = nil;

@implementation LocationManagerSingleton
@synthesize locationManager, location, delegate;

#pragma mark - Singleton Methods -

+ (LocationManagerSingleton*)sharedInstance {

    static LocationManagerSingleton *_sharedInstance;
    if(!_sharedInstance) {
        static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
        dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
            _sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
            });
        }

        return _sharedInstance;
}



+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {    

    return [self sharedInstance];
}


- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return self;    
}

#if (!__has_feature(objc_arc))

- (id)retain {  

    return self;    
}

- (unsigned)retainCount {
    return UINT_MAX;  //denotes an object that cannot be released
}

- (void)release {
    //do nothing
}

- (id)autorelease {

    return self;    
}
#endif

#pragma mark - Custom Methods -

// Add your custom methods here
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 5;
        self.locationManager.purpose = @"This app uses your location for Augmented Reality";
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];

        NSLog(@"LocationManager initialized with accuracy best for Navigation");
        NSLog(@"CUrrent Latitude: %f, Current Longitude: %f",locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude,locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude);
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate Methods -
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation*)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation*)oldLocation
{
    /*…some filer method to check if the new location is good …*/
    bool good = YES;
    if (good)
    {
        [self.delegate locationUpdate:newLocation];
    }
    //self.location = newLocation;
    //NSLog(@"Updated: %@",newLocation);    
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    /* ... */

}


@end
```

Comment: What differences do you get? Are you clearing it from multitasking between runs?

Comment: yes, i am even deleting the program, its funny because if i use the previous version everything runs perfectly, that version doesnt use a singleton but instead just calls a location manager in every view. if i use the singleton then it creates those weird results, so i thought that i had done my singleton incorrectly

Comment: Where is _sharedInstance actually defined?

Comment: in the implementation file the first part, or do you mean where do i create it? i just do something like LocationManagerSingleton *LManager; (in the header) and MManager = [LotionManagerSingleton sharedInstance]; (in the implementation)

Comment: Never mind - I'm going blind! Why are you using GCD in your sharedInstance method? (Have you tried just `@sychronized`?)

Comment: im not sure what you mean. is that the once predicate? could you explain what you mean please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it seems that OpenGL was causing the problem. My theory was that since a pointer variable used for texturing was inside a loop when the localization manager updated and redraw this variable would get messed up because it was being reinitialized everyrun but the value wouldnt be set to 0, and since opengl has the pointer to the adress not to the pointer it would read corrupted data (since the loop might have updated that space until opengl was told the new adress of the variable). Still i have no idea why it worked perfectly while hooked up to the computer and not by itself.